# making Image for GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, packer

I use packer build command to make imge for GCP when I ran this command I face this error

== googlecompute: Error creating instance: 1 error(s) occurred:
== googlecompute: 
== googlecompute: * The user does not have access to service account 'service-76109290418@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  User: 'farzin-second-test-project@farzin-second-test-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account
B

I add service account user role to my service account but still I have Issue could you please Help me in this regard , Is anybody have any Idea about that?

Comment: Are both service accounts `service-76109290418` and `farzin-second-test-project` belong to the same project?

Answer (score 0):

yes, they are both belong to same project